# How change short keys in Vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, omnicomplete, emmet

I am a new user in Vim. How change these keys in [Zen Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_Coding),

<kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

To

<kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>

---

And also change in omni,

<kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>

To

<kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>

How can I do that?

Comment: You need to edit your question so that it is understandable.

Comment: i am sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you to type:

```
:help map.txt
```

inside vim, you'll find all the explanation to understand how to do it.

You can't use the same shortcut for 'zencoding' plugin and for an omnicomplete function; anyway you could add to your .vimrc:

```
imap <C-j> <C-y>
```

But I suggest not to use 'C-j' as 'j' is always related to movement in vim; use 'leader' (`:help leader`) which is targeted to user shortcuts, instead.

Comment: thanks eolo I made a mistake, I mean ,<c-e> for zencoding and <c-j>for omin .. Thanks for the advice

Comment: " for zencoding

imap <C-e> <C-y>,

" for omnifunc

imap <C-j> <C-x><C-o>

Answer (score 4):

You may follow the answer provided by @eolo999, but I suggest you to read zencoding documentation and add the following to the vimrc:

```
" Note the `nore'. You must use it where possible "
" in order not to get remapping problems when your vimrc grows up "
inoremap <C-j> <C-x><C-o>

" from :h zencoding-customize-keymappings "
let g:user_zen_expandabbr_key='<C-e>'
```